# How can I extract a column that compares two columns of two different dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm little bit stuck in R

I have two dataframe.

I Want to compare two column from different dataframe and extract values of another column based on the matching position of the 2 columns compared.

example data :

```
test=data.frame(a=seq(1,10,by=1))

test2=data.frame(x=c(1.1,1.3,2.5,4.2,1.2,3.6,3.7,8.8,9.9,4.1),y=seq(1,10,by=1))
```

Suppose I have these data. I want the value of x in test2 for which test$a and test2$y are matching

```
extract_test=test2[test2$y %in% test$a,]
```

Will give me all the dataframe for the matching values in test2$y and test$a. But I only want test2$x for test2$y==test$a

Comment: Provide sample data frame

Comment: Please don't share data as images. Use `dput(head(df,n))` and copy-paste its output to your question. Choose n as necessary for reproducibility. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so all you want is `mean_test=df_half_data_mean_with_NA[df_half_data_mean_with_NA$range_mean %in% test$a,1:2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which()`.

You can try finding out which rows of the logical test result in `TRUE`:

```
mean_test <- newdf[which(olddf$range_mean %in% test$a), 1:2]
```

This should return the row numbers of those rows where the test is `TRUE` and will subsequently subset your data frame accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that do the job also

Answer (score 1):

```
extract_test=test2[test2$y %in% test$a,1]
[1] 1.1 1.3 2.5 4.2 1.2 3.6 3.7 8.8 9.9 4.1
```

Is this what you're looking for? Just select the columns you want to extract as the second element of the subset.

Or with your original data:

```
mean_test=df_half_data_mean_with_NA[df_half_data_mean_with_NA$range_mean %in% test$a,1]
```

Comment: Yes it's that, I was pretty close... Thanks you